# How to grow round shape on top(maple trees)?

Tags: trees, maple

I have a few speciments of Acer pseudoplatanus and Acer platanoides. I want to grow them, so they will have trunk without branches in bottom part and nice round "ball" at the top as that is often in urban landscape in cities.

I don't know when and how much should I trim them, so I ask you. Should I wait till the end of the growth period to trim new branches or do it now? I want tree to be about 2 meter high, a little more than ordinary human. I am located in continental Europe, so now we have growth period.

I added a photo how it looks like and another one what should it look like. The first image is one of my trees and the second image is the shape I want in the future.

Thank you!

[image: my maple tree]
[image: Desired shape in the end]

Answer (score 1):

I think the pictures show [Acer platanoides "Globosum"](https://landscapeplants.oregonstate.edu/plants/acer-platanoides-globosum) which is described as

> A grafted...tree displaying a formal broad, globe shaped head which
> needs no pruning

Most maples show strong [apical dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_dominance) and are not suitable for pruning into a globe shape.

If you tried to prune your sapling by topping the central leader toy will get a lot of [adventitious growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_development#Buds_and_shoots) which will not have a good attachment to the trunk as the multiple stems grow.